# Redux store updating, but React views is not

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios, redux-thunk

Hi when i console log my components props (passed down from redux) i get the initial state which is null. however using the react inspector i have the result of the axios request. I tried reading dozens of similar problems but cannot seen to resolve my issue.
[image]

**Actions**

```
import { searchService } from  '../api/searchService';    

export const actions = {
 FETCH_USERS: 'FETCH_USERS',
}

export const searchUsers = () => dispatch => {
  searchService.get('/search')
    .then((result) => {
      dispatch({
        type: actions.FETCH_USERS,
        payload: result
      })
    })
}
```

**Reducers**

```
import { actions } from '../actions';

export default (state = null, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case actions.FETCH_USERS:
      return action.payload;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

**Search Component**

```
function mapStateToProps ({search}) {
  return {search};
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  searchUsers: () => dispatch(searchUsers())
});


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(withAuth()(Search));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the Reducer
First you should make an initial state, and then you need to edit this state in order for redux to feel the changes and update

Check the code below and let me know if it worked for you.

```
import { actions } from '../actions';

const INITIAL_STATE= {search: ""};

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case actions.FETCH_USERS:
      return {...state, search: action.payload};
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey Willy, I used your code and now all my console log does is: search: "". However my React debugger still has the right state ( the fetch data).....